# conditional sprintf codeigniter php

Tags: php, xml, codeigniter, printf

We are creating 2 applications based on the same codeigniter codebase. Both of these applications make use of language based XML files (we can't use the native CI lang lib), so we have one XML file per language per app.

Within these XML files is text which, depending on the application you are looking at, is formatted differently when output. (we are loading the XML with simple XML and then outputting the required element by name)

An example XML extract for app 1 might be:

```
<instructions>
    <instruction>**<strong>**Lorem ipsum dolor sit**</strong>** amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed doeiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</instruction>
</instructions>
```

And example app 2 extract might be:

```
<instructions>
    <instruction>Lorem ipsum dolor sitamet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed doeiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et **<br /><br />**dolore magna aliqua</instruction>
</instructions>
```

Basically, these XML files need to contain different markup to format them when they are output within the PHP. Both examples above would be echo'd as $app->instructions->instruction.

Currently I have achieved this the variations in formattings using CDATA placeholders which I then sprintf and replace. However this is not flexible enough in my opinion needing multiple params within the sprintf function to replace what could potentially be a large number of markup elements. So far the most I have needed to replace is 6 CDATA tokens.

Compound this by the fact I've also had to make the sprintf conditional based on the app being loaded. Made worse still by the fact I've opted to do this in the controller so to not pollute the HTML with un-necessary PHP.

To cut to the chase what I'd like to achieve is the following:

- XML kept clear of HTML markup
- HTML kept clear of, or at least minimise the use of, PHP
- Definitely no HTML within the controller

It seems I'm compromising one of these which ever way I try to work it.

Comment: BTW, what is your concrete programming question?

Comment: Well, I guess its can anyone recommend a way of separating out the logic whilst remaining flexible on extensibility given the scenario I explain above.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is borderline to answer it, but I try anyway. You formulated three requirements:

1. XML kept clear of HTML markup
2. HTML kept clear of, or at least minimise the use of, PHP
3. Definitely no HTML within the controller

To keep XML clear of HTML markup, just don't put any HTML markup in there. Or if you want to have HTML in there, encode it properly. Like with CDATA or just XML entities:

```
<instructions>
  <instruction>
    &lt;strong&gt;Lorem ipsum dolor sit&lt;/strong&gt; amet, consectetur 
    adipisicing elit, sed doeiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
    aliqua
  </instruction>
</instructions>
```

XML has no problem with that at all and you should not have any problem to obtain that value as well. So that for 1.).

For 2.) I don't understand what you mean. If you want to keep that clear of PHP, don't put any PHP inside. If you put PHP inside, you need to understand that you need to encode it as well (like the HTML) otherwise you would create so called processing instructions (pi) which might not be any problem in itself, however when fetching the data you might run into problems. But anyway, as those translations are static data, you should not put any PHP in there anyway.

Logic dealing with that static data most likely belongs into the view and/or the controller.

For 3.) just don't put any HTML inside the controller and you should be fine to go (place it into what the Codeigniter folks call view, that is the component for HTML templating in Codeigniter).

Comment: Hakre - thank you for your reply. The problem I'm having is mainly about extendability and separation of the code in an MVC framework. The XML should not contain any formatting markup, similarly the controller. The CI view should contain as little logic as possible. So what I'm trying to do is find a way of separating out logic from function whilst being as extendible as possible. My use of sprintf with 5 or 6 replacement parameters feels......dirty.

Comment: I then suggest you don't put that in there. I already wondered why you do so. Just keep the HTML and PHP out of the translation files and you should be fine.